# Why when posting a Delete Action does it manage to get through to my Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a delete button which is nested into a form of method Post. The @Html.BeginForm doesn't have a FormMethod for Delete so I have included the HttpMethodOverride to include HttpVerbs.Delete.

Here is an extract of the code below (its actually part of a dialog box hence the cancel button):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frm-commit-delete" }))
{
    @Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Delete)
    <button id="btn-commit-delete" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
}
```

The problem is that when I click the "Delete" button it is managing to get into my ActionMethod which is not decorated with any HttpVerbs.

For example

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(Guid id)
    {
        var user = await _Service.DeleteUser(id);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

So it managed to get into this action and execute the code. If I add a [HttpGet] then it gets stopped. If I add a [HttpDelete] then it gets through (as I would expect).

My worry (and question) is that why does it get through with no attribute? as I expect the default would be [HttpGet]. This could have security issues.

**EDIT**

I did some more testing after @Peter-b response:

I created a form for each type:

- Get
- Post
- Post (with http methodoverride Delete)
- Get (with http methodoverride Delete)

Here is the cshtml:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Home", new { id = 100 }, FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Delete by Get" />
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Home", new { id = 100 }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = 100 }))
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Delete by Post" />
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Home", new { id = 100 }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = 100 }))
    {
        @Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Delete)
        <input type="submit" value="Delete by Post with HttpMethodOverride Delete" />
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Home", new { id = 100 }, FormMethod.Get, new { id = 100 }))
    {
        @Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Delete)
        <input type="submit" value="Delete by Get with HttpMethodOverride Delete" />
    }
```

and had the Home controller

```
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        var doSomething = 100;

        return View();
    }
```

Clicking each button got through to doSomething

After adding the [HttpDelete] attribute to the Delete Action Method it stopped them all except the third one. This proves @peter-b correct.

I didn't realise this worked like that, but I think in the future I may always mark up the ActionMethods with what I am expecting to be passed to it.

Comment: Asp.net mvc also uses a naming convention based on http method to find actions.

Comment: Im sure this is the case for Web.Api where you have a get post etc methods but I have just done a test  where I have a form for each type and they all get through which matches @Peter-B answer below. Ill edit the above to show what I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[Http....]` attributes work as a filter for what methods are allowed, and without such an attribute there is no filter, and so all methods are allowed.

To summarize:

```
// No attribute -> will respond to METHOD = POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, ...
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(Guid id)
{
}

[HttpDelete] // -> will only respond to METHOD = DELETE
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(Guid id)
{
}
```